# JVZIPN: Params details required

Tags: e-commerce, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to setup JVZoo's IPN (JVZIPN), but I am unable to find a few things about the params returned by it. Here they are:

1. `ctransvendor` where to find this on my jvzoo login? like on sellers dashboard?
2. `ctransreceipt` is this unique? I mean is it unique per transaction? or per customer? I need to find out a complete unique identifier per message (irrespective of Sale, Bill, Cancel etc).
3. `Pass parameters to Download Page` checkbox on the Product Add/Edit page. Will this send my back script the same params as mentioned in JVZIPN? or something else in some other format? Also, will the `ctransreceipt`ctransreceipt be same for both these messages (JVZIPN and the posted data on return page)?
4. `cproditem`: where to find this on Sellers Dashboard? is this the same as the url and buttons of the products setup at jvzoo's seller dashboard?

Can someone tell me about these? Their technical support doesnt seem to answer these questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JVZoo doesn't provide you any account information. You need to create an AccessKey and add that to the MY Account info in the JVZoo Account. The JVZIPN will post to YOUR URL with a $_POST. You will receive all of the info listed in the IPN docs. The $_POST['ctransreceipt'] value will be their receipt id. You will then need to respond back to JVZOO with a print('whatever you want on receipt here');